# How can I run xUnit Unit Tests with VS2015 Preview?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net, visual-studio-2015

I added the "xUnit.net runner for Visual Studio" v0.99.8 via Extensions Manager, but when I open the Test Explorer window, it does not seem to pick up any of my unit tests. Also, the Resharper 9 EAP does which is the only version of Resharper that supports VS2015 does  seem yet to have the plugin for xUnit Test Runner.

How then, can I run xUnit Unit Tests in VS2015 Preview?

Comment: See the issue here https://github.com/xunit/visualstudio.xunit/issues/31

Comment: Installed release of VS 2015 Community with all check box checked. I run XUnit tests without additional installations. But I got crash on running all test at once(all tests are single threaded and only managed code of github.com/EamonNerbonne/ExpressionToCode). So run them in small batches.

Answer (score 14):

You can find the answer here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-asp-net-features-in-visual-studio-2015-preview-and-vs2013-update-4.aspx

> Visual Studio supports running and debugging for ASP.NET 5 xUnit tests through test explorer. All you need to do is add the xUnit dependencies and test commands to the test project's project.json file, as shown below (NOTE: To install the xUnit packages you will need to add https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2 as a NuGet package source):

```
"dependencies": {
    "Xunit.KRunner": "1.0.0-beta1"
},

"commands": {
    "test": "Xunit.KRunner"
},
```

---

If anyone is asking how to add https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2 as a NuGet package source...
here are the steps:

1. In Visual Studio 2015 Preview go to Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources
2. Click the Plus (Add) button at the top (see image below)
3. Enter the Name and Source like in the image below (NOTE: be sure to click the Update button after entering the Name and Source)
   [image]

Happy coding!

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the Test Explorer to discover the tests when the project contains more than a few tests, for example, with tests from the Mvc project on GitHub.  I filed a bug for this on Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1099770

Comment: After I added the NuGet package source, I wasn't able to find the `xunit.Krunner` package, all xunit that I can find were: `xunit.execution` and `xunit.runner.utility`

Comment: @Jaider maybe there are updates... please look at this: https://github.com/aspnet/Testing/wiki/How-to-create-test-projects
`
    {
        "dependencies": {
            "MyProject": "1.0.0-*",
            "xunit.runner.kre": "1.0.0-*"
        },
        "frameworks": {
            "aspnet50": { },
            "aspnetcore50": { }
        },
        "commands": {
            "test": "xunit.runner.kre"
            }
    }`

Comment: According to xUnits [twitter](https://twitter.com/xunit/status/569879015676190720) which ref this blog post: http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-aspnet.html, we should use xunit.runner.aspnet.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add reference to these 3 nuget packages:

```
"xunit": "2.1.0.0-beta1-build2945",
"xunit.runner.aspnet": "2.1.0.0-beta1-build60",
"xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.1.0.0-beta1-build1051"
```

Check this article for more info:
http://blog.developers.ba/unit-integration-testing-in-asp-net-5-and-visual-studio-2015-using-xunit-net/

Comment: what's the purpose of `"xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.1.0.0-beta1-build1051"` ? for me it works without it.

Comment: That is strange. I thought that xunit.runner.visualstudio is for running test from visual studio and xunit.runner.aspnet for supporting new aspnet and running tests from console.

Comment: No. xunit.runner.visualstudio is used for desktop, PCL, Windows, and Windows Phone DLLs. xunit.runner.dnx is *both* the console and Visual Studio runner in one package.

Answer (score 5):

With visual studio 2015 RC I could not get tests to work with the following:

```
"xunit": "2.1.0-beta2-*",
"xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta2-*"
```

But tests started showing up in the Test Explorer after changing the casing of the first letter "x" to "X"

```
"Xunit": "2.1.0-beta2-*",
"Xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta2-*"
```

When I change it back to lower case it fails. I have not yet found a way to get these tests to show up in the latest version of Resharper at this time.

Here is the post I followed to get this far and everything worked except for the casing for some reason:

http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html

I know this will be out of date soon, but hopefully it helps someone in the mean time :)

Comment: That's definitely not the case. Everybody I know who uses it -- myself included -- has no problem with lower-case x.

It appears that NuGet package names are not case sensitive, so my best guess as to why one works and the other doesn't is that you have a corrupted package cache.

Comment: Whoah - I actually just ran in to this! and though, the casing X x thing was crazy, but same thing happened for me!

Comment: I had the same issue - make sure the nuget package names start with capital X. Otherwise, change the package versions via project.json and dnu restore to make them capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding managing / running the tests through test explorer, it is available through nuget.
I had to install package xunit.runner.visualstudio version 0.99.9-build1021 in the test projects.
After building the solution, the tests showed up fine and I was able to run them.

BTW, this was for a windows service but should work for ASP.NET/Web projects.